# SSIS performance

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sqlperformance

I am working on an intel core-i3, 64-bit machine with just 4GB RAM.OS is Windows 7 and SQL Server 2012, evaluation is installed.

I am trying to do some SSIS development in it. i need to load a flatfile with 0.5 million records (156 columns/ approximately Row length of 3500 in total). SQL engine and SSIS engine are running in same machine.
As I am using a small Pc, I dont expect high performance in my machine. See the below print screens.

Once my package starts running, the memory usage reaches maximum in no time.

[image]

[image]

See processes tab
[image]

---

The CPU usage is just 3%, and memory may be 96%,

**1. Even after closing, SSDT and SQL server management studio, the
    memory still remains at 95%, until I restart MSSQL service. Why is
    it behaving So?**

**2. How can I KNOW the I/O efficiency?**

thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Because by default SQL Server uses memory and doesn't let it go. Closing SSMS is irrelevant. Change the Maximum Server memory if you want to limit it (only if it is actually affecting performance) 2. I'm by no means a performance expert but look into perfmon and DMV views. You'll very quickly realize that 'I/O efficiency' is a very simple question with a very complex answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set your flat file input to Fast parse.

This is a better guide.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BrianKnight/ssis/780/loading-flat-files-faster-in-ssis-with-fastparse

Old guide
http://henkvandervalk.com/speeding-up-ssis-bulk-inserts-into-sql-server

Comment: As I told early, I am loading the flat file to an SQL destination. Out of 156 columns, all are loaded as string into the stage table. We are doing so, as this will be kept as a reference data. 
Looks like Fast Parse can be applied for columns of datatype, DT_I1, DT_I2, DT_I4, DT_I8, DT_UI1, DT_UI2, DT_UI4, DT_UI8, DT_DBTIMESTAMP, DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET, DT_DATE, DT_DBDATE, DT_DBTIME, DT_DBTIME2, or DT_FILETIME , only.

Comment: Since fast parse will not work for your string data type, try setting your Data access mode to one of the "Fast Load" options. This is found in your OLE DB Destination Editor under the Data Flow.

Comment: I changed, the DB recovery model from FULL --> Simple.
There is a 10-15% increase in loading speed..

Answer (score 2):

As per your problem, you should consider decreasing the buffer size or decreasing the batch size. For example, decreasing the DefaultBufferSize and DefaultBufferMaxRows.

Instead of using fast-load in OLE DB destination or SQL destination, you can use ODBC with appropriate batch size.

Due to the limitation of your machine, try to use parallelism properly if there is any.